how to share headers among SequentialTaskSet tasks called by HttpUser class?
I need to pass headers to a sequence of API calls (all of which extend both SequentialTaskSet and ApiUser; ApiUser being an extension of HttpUser(, the Locust documentation for TaskSet told me that nesting was the best way to do that. However, I run into type errors (marked with # ERROR:). What's the best way to fix them?
What the ApiUser looks like (the post_headers are needed for authentication):
from locust import HttpUser
class ApiUser(HttpUser):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.users = None
        self.access_token = None
        self.refresh_token = None
        self.headers = None
        self.post_headers = None
    
    def post_helper(self, url: str, json: dict):
        """do something with error handling"""
    
    def get_helper(self, path: str):
        """do something with error handling"""

What the SequentialTaskSet looks like (PrepTasks will be called elsewhere, the problem is in PrepTasks itself):
from api_user import ApiUser
from locust import SequentialTaskSet, task
from typing import Dict, Any
class PrepTasks(ApiUser):
    tasks = [QuickStartSequence] # ERROR: not defined
    def __init__(self, post_headers: Dict[str, Any], *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.post_headers = post_headers
        
    class QuickStartSequence(SequentialTaskSet):
        tasks = [Task1, Task2, Task3] # ERROR: not defined

    class Task1(SequentialTaskSet, ApiUser):
        @task
        def get_call1(self):
            return self.get_helper("some-path/some-sub") # ApiUser.get_helper()

        @task
        def stop(self):
            self.interrupt()

    class Task2(SequentialTaskSet, ApiUser):
        @task
        def get_call2(self):
            return self.get_helper("some-path/some-sub") # ApiUser.get_helper()

        @task
        def stop(self):
            self.interrupt()

    class Task3(SequentialTaskSet, ApiUser):
        @task
        def get_call3(self):
            return self.get_helper("some-path/some-sub") # ApiUser.get_helper()

        @task
        def stop(self):
            self.interrupt()


Start by moving QuickStartSequence to module level, at the top. You cant define it inside your user class like that.

Oh, and why are you using SequentialTaskSet at all? Most problems can be solved by just putting everything in a single task instead :)

better in question add link to documentation which told you about nesting.

@Cyberwiz using SequentialTaskSet because the def stop(self): tasks would 'force' Task2 and Task3 to run. my previous problem was that only Task1 would run
